# Javascript error adding output! TypeError: tickvalues is null See your browser Javascript console for more details

Tags: ipython

I am trying to run below code in jupyter notebook.

`df.groupby(['Gender'])['ApplicantIncome'].mean().plot()`

But end up with the error:

> Javascript error adding output! TypeError: tickvalues is null See your
>   browser Javascript console for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was trying to include mpld3. Try excluding them if you have any.

```
# import mpld3
# mpld3.enable_notebook()
```